# Any current examples using Flask and jquery file upload by blueimp?

Tags: flask, jquery-file-upload

I'm wondering if there are any current examples of using the jquery file upload plugin by blueimp with the flask framework. If anybody has some code snippet to share I'd be grateful.

They layout seems to be fine and I can add a file and it previews well. The issue is that when I try to go and upload it, I get this kind of an error:
[12:47:58.690] POST [HTTP/1.0 400 BAD REQUEST 7ms]

On the server side, I don't even have a valid file object that I can print out so I believe the issue here is with the javascript portion of the code (or maybe I'm wrong on this as well). Here is the relevant code I'm currently using on the template side:

```
<form action="{{ url_for('upload') }}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    !-- The global progress bar -->
    <div id="progress" class="progress progress-success progress-striped">
    <div class="bar"></div>
    </div>
    <!-- The fileinput-button span is used to style the file input field as button -->
    <span class="btn btn-success fileinput-button">
    <i class="icon-plus icon-white"></i>
    <span>Add files...</span>
    <!-- The file input field used as target for the file upload widget -->
    <input id="fileupload" type="file" name="files[]" multiple>
    </span>
    <br><br>

    <!-- The container for the uploaded files -->
     <div id="files" class="files"></div>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='assets/js/jquery.ui.widget.js') }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='assets/js/jquery.iframe-transport.js') }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='assets/js/jquery.fileupload.js') }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='assets/js/jquery.fileupload-process.js') }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='assets/js/jquery.fileupload-image.js') }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='assets/js/jquery.fileupload-audio.js') }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='assets/js/jquery.fileupload-video.js') }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='assets/js/jquery.fileupload-validate.js') }}"></script>

<script>
/*jslint unparam: true, regexp: true */
/*global window, $ */
$(function () {
    'use strict';
    // Change this to the location of your server-side upload handler:
    var uploadButton = $('<button/>')
            .addClass('btn')
            .prop('disabled', true)
            .text('Processing...')
            .on('click', function () {
                var $this = $(this),
                    data = $this.data();
                $this
                    .off('click')
                    .text('Abort')
                    .on('click', function () {
                        $this.remove();
                        data.abort();
                    });
                data.submit().always(function () {
                    $this.remove();
                });
            });
    $('#fileupload').fileupload({
        url: '/upload',
        dataType: 'json',
        autoUpload: false,
        acceptFileTypes: /(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/i,
        maxFileSize: 5000000, // 5 MB
        // Enable image resizing, except for Android and Opera,
        // which actually support image resizing, but fail to
        // send Blob objects via XHR requests:
        disableImageResize: /Android(?!.*Chrome)|Opera/
            .test(window.navigator.userAgent),
        previewMaxWidth: 100,
        previewMaxHeight: 100,
        previewCrop: true
    }).on('fileuploadadd', function (e, data) {
        data.context = $('<div/>').appendTo('#files');
        $.each(data.files, function (index, file) {
            var node = $('<p/>')
                    .append($('<span/>').text(file.name));
            if (!index) {
                node
                    .append('<br>')
                    .append(uploadButton.clone(true).data(data));
            }
            node.appendTo(data.context);
        });
    }).on('fileuploadprocessalways', function (e, data) {
        var index = data.index,
            file = data.files[index],
            node = $(data.context.children()[index]);

        if (file.preview) {
            node
                .prepend('<br>')
                .prepend(file.preview);
        }
        if (file.error) {
            node
                .append('<br>')
                .append(file.error);
        }
        if (index + 1 === data.files.length) {
            data.context.find('button')
                .text('Upload')
                .prop('disabled', !!data.files.error);
        }
    }).on('fileuploadprogressall', function (e, data) {
        var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
        $('#progress .bar').css(
            'width',
            progress + '%'
        );
    }).on('fileuploaddone', function (e, data) {
        $.each(data.result.files, function (index, file) {
            var link = $('<a>')
                .attr('target', '_blank')
                .prop('href', file.url);
            $(data.context.children()[index])
                .wrap(link);
        });
    }).on('fileuploadfail', function (e, data) {
        $.each(data.result.files, function (index, file) {
            var error = $('<span/>').text(file.error);
            $(data.context.children()[index])
                .append('<br>')
                .append(error);
        });
    }).prop('disabled', !$.support.fileInput)
        .parent().addClass($.support.fileInput ? undefined : 'disabled');
});
</script>
```

Here is the upload handler:

```
UPLOAD_FOLDER = 'static/tmp/'
ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS = set(['txt', 'pdf', 'png', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif'])

def _handleUpload(files):
    if not files:
       return None
    filenames = []
    saved_files_urls = []
    for key, file in files.iteritems():
        if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
            filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
            print os.path.join(UPLOAD_FOLDER, filename)
            file.save(os.path.join(UPLOAD_FOLDER, filename))
            saved_files_urls.append(url_for('uploaded_file', filename=filename))
            filenames.append("%s" % (file.filename))
            print saved_files_urls[0]

    return filenames

@app.route('/upload', methods=['POST'])
def upload():
    try:
        message = request.values['message']
        files = request.files
        print files, message

        uploaded_files = _handleUpload(files)

        return jsonify({'files': uploaded_files})
    except:
        raise
        return jsonify({'status': 'error'})
```

Comment: This one is about 8 months old: https://bitbucket.org/adampetrovic/flask-uploader

Comment: Thanks, but I've been having some trouble getting the basic_ui version of the jquery file uploader to work nicely with flask. The example is a good one, but I'm not setting it up with S3 unfortunately. I'm also a bit new to this so its a bit more of a learning curve for me.

Comment: Post your Flask `/upload` handler please.

Comment: Added the relevant upload handler. Thanks Mark.

Answer (score 0):

Change upload method to:

```
@app.route('/upload', methods=['POST'])
def upload():
    try:
        files = request.files
        print files

        uploaded_files = _handleUpload(files)

        return jsonify({'files': uploaded_files})
    except:
        raise
        return jsonify({'status': 'error'})
```